# Burp suite Sequencer error

Tags: id

Hola amigos disculpen alguien podria ayudarme ando usando burp suite y quiero analizar un token con el sequencer voy a la pestaña "Proxy" agarro un request que tenga uan cookie o inicio de session le doy clic derecho y lo mando al Sequencer "Live Capture Request" y aparece ahi (adjunto la imagen) pero no cuando doy clic en "Start Capture" aparece el error de Invalid custom location configuration alguien sabe como resolverlo ??? gracias por su tiempo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola para todos los que les llegue a pasar este error yo utilice Ubuntu 18 y la versión Professional / Community 2020.5

El error se solucionó con este comando

```
sudo apt-get full-upgrade
```